# Assistance with Javascript question (student-in-training)

Tags: javascript, for-loop, object

If anyone is able to help explain why my submitted code is incorrect **and** *why* the provided correct code works and why, I'd be very grateful.

**Problem/Instructions:**

> Write a function called "getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty".
>
> Given an object and a key, "getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty"
> returns an array containing the elements within the array, located at
> the given key, that are greater than 10.
>
> Notes:
>
> If the array is empty, it should return an empty array.
>
> If the array contains no elements greater than 10, it should return an
> empty array.
>
> If the property at the given key is not an array, it should return an
> empty array.
>
> If there is no property at the key, it should return an empty array.

```
*Example output: var obj = {
  key: [1, 20, 30]
};
var output = getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty(obj, 'key');
console.log(output); // --> [20, 30]*
```

**My code (which does not fulfill all 5 passing requirements):**

```
function getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty(obj, key) {
    let newArr = [];
    if (Array.isArray(obj[key]) === false || obj[key] !== [] || obj[key] === undefined){
        return [];
    }
    for (let i in obj[key]){
        if (i > 10){
            newArr.push(i);
        }
    }
    return newArr;
}
```

**My code results:**

> ✗ it should return an array containing all the elements greater than
> 10 in the array located at key   Error:
> expected [] to deeply equal [ 20, 40 ]
>
> ✓ it should return an empty array if the array has no elements greater
> than 10
>
> ✓ it should return an empty array if the array is empty
>
> ✓ it should return an empty array if the property is not an array
>
> ✓ it should return an empty array if the property does not exist

**Correct code (found online):**

```
> function getElementsGreaterThan10AtProperty(obj, key) {
  var greaterThan10 = [];
  for (var property in obj) {
    if (property === key) {
      for (var i = 0; i < obj[key].length; ++i) {
        if (obj[key][i] > 10) {
          greaterThan10.push(obj[key][i]);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return greaterThan10;
}
```

I simply don't understand why mine doesn't work, why the logic is wrong. And I don't understand the logic of the correct code. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: `obj[key] !== []` will always be `true`.

Comment: Also that "correct" code is needlessly complicated; there's no point to the outer `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

In `let i in obj[key]` the variable `i` will not be the value (E.g. 20), but the index.
So you can get the value by `obj[key][i]`.

Also Pointy is correct in his comment that `obj[key] !== []` does not make sense and should be removed.

This is also a good example where functional code is nicer, as instead of the for loop you could use: `return obj[key].filter(val => val > 10);`

Answer (score 0):

change this `obj[key] !== []` to `!obj[key].length`